# Sorting in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle10g

I am having 600 records in oracle DB which are to be sorted using their column in ascending and descending. While sorting we are getting an issue like the records are breaking into subsets and gets sorted(for eg) the first 250 records are sorted in the order A-Z and like that its splitting the records and gets sorted?

Iam not getting the sorted list for all the 600 records

Now i am getting output like below
a
b
.
.
.
z
a
..
..
..
z
i want like 
a
b
c
..

z

Any suggestions?

Comment: What query are you using to do the sort?

Comment: Show your query. Oracle is case sensitive, are you getting a..z,A..Z for your results?

Comment: Query : select customer_name from customertable order by customer_name asc

Comment: show the actual results also - post them the pastebin as they will be large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be issue of regarding upper Case and Lower Case customer Name modify your query according to that.